# XAML can't see members of an IList - Inconsistent accessibility?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am building a WPF screen with buttons created from an IList in a C# class.  It builds and displays the correct number of buttons; but, does not display the text on the buttons that is built from the list items.

I have done this before in another class/screen and it worked fine.

I noticed when debugging that if I hover over the List object in the class that works (BibList), I get the fly-over tip "Inconsistent accessibility: property type 'System.Collections.Generic.IList' is less accessible than property 'BurnIn.UI.Modules.Operations.VieModels.OvenViewModel.BibList'

I don't get that message in the class that works and it matches what I am seeing (that the XAML can't see the SlotInfo information); but, everything is public so I don't see where the accessibility issue is.

Here is the code that declares the list:

```
namespace BurnIn.UI.Modules.Operations.ViewModels
{
    public class SlotInfo
    {
        public int SlotNumber;
        public string BibName;
    }

    public class OvenViewModel : OvenViewModelBase
    {
        private List<SlotInfo> m_BibList = new List<SlotInfo>();
        public IList<SlotInfo> BibList
        {
            get { return m_BibList; }
        }
```

Comment: What is the accessibility of OvenViewModelBase?

Comment: OvenViewModelBase is also Public

Note: The problem appears the be with the accessibility of 'SlotInfo' which is declared as public and (to me) seems more accessible that BibList since it is not class scoped.

Comment: The error message here is misleading because this code can't make that error in earnest. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx is the MSDN on IList and shows it as public, so your code *can't* make anything that is more accessible than IList. The error is a red herring and the true problem is something else. I'm not seeing it here though.

Comment: It does appear that the message is a Red Herring.  This morning with a fresh perspective and encouragement to look eslewhere, I noticed that the SlotInfo elements were members rather than properties and that WPF probably could only see properties.  I changed them to properties and now the elements display properly (even though I still get the bogus fly-over tip).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the SlotInfo elements were members rather than properties.  The fly-over "help" tip was a Red Herring.

Answer (score 0):

It may have to do with the casting between a List and an IList. What happens if you change the types to match?

Like so

```
namespace BurnIn.UI.Modules.Operations.ViewModels
{
public class SlotInfo
{
    public int SlotNumber;
    public string BibName;
}

public class OvenViewModel : OvenViewModelBase
{
    var m_BibList = new List<SlotInfo>();
    public IList<SlotInfo> BibList
    {
        get { return m_BibList; }
    }
```

or this

```
namespace BurnIn.UI.Modules.Operations.ViewModels
{
public class SlotInfo
{
    public int SlotNumber;
    public string BibName;
}

public class OvenViewModel : OvenViewModelBase
{
    List<SlotInfo> m_BibList = new List<SlotInfo>();
    public List<SlotInfo> BibList
    {
        get { return m_BibList; }
    }
```